# install valgrind, Fatal error at startup

Tags: valgrind

I am installing Valgrind but encounter some problems. The info of my platform:

```
Linux xx-ThinkPad-X61 3.2.0-39-generic-pae #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 27 22:25:11 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I follows the installation instruction of the README file in the valgrind folder. 
./configure ->make -> sudo make install.

I can't understand the following reminder in the README file, I just overlooked it.

```
Important!  Do not move the valgrind installation into a place
different from that specified by --prefix at build time.  This will
cause things to break in subtle ways, mostly when Valgrind handles
fork/exec calls.
```

after typing "valgrind ls -l", error appears:

```
xx@xx-ThinkPad-X61:~/Downloads/valgrind-3.8.1$ valgrind ls -l
==7674== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7674== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7674== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7674== Command: ls -l
==7674== 

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:  
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux.so.2
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux.so.2
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:  
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

Could someone give some suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I also faced this error, but finally resolved in below manner.

I am having 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04, and my executable is 32 bit. When I run my 32 bit executable with valgrind I got this same error. This error was not resolved even after installing `libc6-dbg` (using command `apt-get install libc6-dbg`).

Later I found like whatever `libc6-dbg` present in my machine was 64 bit and valgrind requires a 32 bit `libc6-dbg` to run my 32 bit executable. After installing 32 bit `libc6-dbg` (using the command `apt-get install libc6-dbg:i386`) it started working.

Comment: I had to go through some hoops to add i386 arch on my amd64 machine but after that everything went really easy. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I had to do the following to get this to work:

`dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install libc6-dbg:i386`

Comment: I installed `libc6-dbg:i386` and I still get the same error. I'm on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

```sh
apt install -y libc6-dbg
```

It worked for me. (Note: *without* `:i386`.)
A hunch is that Valgrind might have upgraded to 64-bit since the answer
by rashok was written.

Answer (score 3):

Valgrind indicates it cannot work because it is missing the libc debug info,
and it indicates which package has to be installed to solve that.
In your case (Ubuntu), you must install
    libc6-dbg

Comment: ,thanks. I realized that and tried to install libc6-dbg. but my ubuntu 12.04 encountered a problem with x systems, and I am not able to enter GUI. I will update my state with valgrind afterwards.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I install libc6-dbg and still get this error.

Comment: @Erik : found a solution for this problem.