# How to fix the fatal error at startup in valgrind (connected with libc6-dbg and libc6-dbg:i386 )

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, valgrind

Have this problem that can't fix any way. I tried to install libc6-dbg and libc6-dbg:i386 and it didn't help.(I have 64 bit Ubuntu 19.10).

```
valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
    valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
    valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
    valgrind:  
    valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
    valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
    valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
    valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    valgrind:  
    valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
    valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
    valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
    valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
    valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
    valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
    valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
    valgrind:  
    valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
    valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
    valgrind:  
    valgrind:  Note that if you are debugging a 32 bit process on a
    valgrind:  64 bit system, you will need a corresponding 32 bit debuginfo
    valgrind:  package (e.g. libc6-dbg:i386).
    valgrind:  
    valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

So, show you installed packages. As you see everything is correctly installed, but doesn' work. I don't know what to do more to make it work.

package for amd64

```
Package: libc6-dbg
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: debug
Installed-Size: 44570
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: glibc
Version: 2.30-0ubuntu2
Provides: libc-dbg
Depends: libc6 (= 2.30-0ubuntu2)
Description: GNU C Library: detached debugging symbols
 This package contains the detached debugging symbols for the GNU C
 library.
Homepage: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html
Original-Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>
```

package for i386

```
Package: libc6-dbg
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: debug
Installed-Size: 35315
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Multi-Arch: same
Source: glibc
Version: 2.30-0ubuntu2
Provides: libc-dbg
Depends: libc6 (= 2.30-0ubuntu2)
Description: GNU C Library: detached debugging symbols
 This package contains the detached debugging symbols for the GNU C
 library.
Homepage: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html
Original-Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers <debian-glibc@lists.debian.org>
```

Comment: Along with @sam's comment, please let us know if you successfully installed `libc6-dbg` or not, and any output that might've been produced by the installation of this package.

Comment: @S.S.Anne, i added needed information and edited the names

Comment: Thank your for the edits. That is weird. Did you install `valgrind` yourself or did you use the package?

Comment: @S.S.Anne firstly i installed by myself with package(tat.bz2 archive) from official site. Did it by steps and i don’t think I was wrong. Then i saw this message and installed libc6 for i386 and this still doesn't work.

Comment: @S.S.Anne, and could you say please how to do this now  ? How to fully delete this and reinstall right ?

Comment: You run `sudo make uninstall` from the directory that you built Valgrind in and then you run `sudo apt-get install valgrind`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne wow, thank you so much!!! This works now. So, I know that I'm already tired of my questions. But can you say why this way of installation right and why i had problems with (tar.bz2) installation ?

Comment: The distribution adds special paths to Valgrinds debug search path.

Comment: On Linux there are mandatory redirects for `strlen` and `index` in `ld.so`. What do you see when you run Valgrind with the --trace-symtab=yes option?

Comment: This problem has now been fixed in the git repository, as of commit db07db4c8706

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install valgrind, Fatal error at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721919/install-valgrind-fatal-error-at-startup)

Answer (score 0):

valgrind is looking for files in the wrong path.

Ubuntu has a mess in `/usr/lib/debug`. If you unify `/usr/lib/debug/lib` and `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib` it should work.

At least, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04. As user phd has pointed out in their comment, this is a Valgrind bug that has been fixed in commit [db07db4c8706d17124a621a254bee1b6f08d2e1d](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=valgrind.git;a=commitdiff;h=db07db4c8706d17124a621a254bee1b6f08d2e1d;hp=3a2711c659ac839934f13e0529e14d6c15325383)

You can build valgrind easily by running something like

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git
cd valgrind
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j
sudo make install
```

(please don't run commands as sudo if you're not sure what they do)